# Can't resolve all parameters for APICalls: (?)

Tags: angular

[console in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAA7r.png)

I have this issue for a few days now, I can not find a solution.
See the image for console log.

This is my code from the APICalls class:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class APICalls{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  public authenticate(username:string, password:string):void{

    const req = this.http.post('http://localhost:9050/user/authenticate', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
        .subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log(res);
          },
          err => {
            console.log("Error occured");
          }
        );
}
```

}

Code from app module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And the code from the login component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { APICalls } from '../classes/APICalls';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [APICalls]
})
export class LoginComponent {
  public username: string;
  public password: string;

  constructor(private router:Router, private api:APICalls){ }

  public login(){
     alert("TEST:" + " username: " + this.username + " password: " + 
this.password);
    this.api.authenticate(this.username, this.password);
  }

  public navToRegister(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/register');
  }
}
```

There is something wrong with the httpclient parameter in the constructor, but I don't know how to fix it, I've tried removing the constructor, but this gives another error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @Injectable decorator in your APICalls service.

```
@Injectable()
export class APICalls{
...
}
```

Also add/import APICalls service in provider array of AppModule.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APICalls } from '../classes/APICalls';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [APICalls],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `@Injectable` decorator to `APICalls` service , when the service has no dependencies you can remove `@Injectable` decorator , but in you case you have inject `HttpClient`

```
@Injectable()
export class APICalls{
...
}
```

Check this [Why do we have to use @Injectable() in Angular?](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2016/12/08/angular-injectable/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things. APICalls is a service and you need to declare it as a service. In order to do that,

1. Put @Injectable() decorator to APICalls

   `@Injectable()
     export class APICalls{
      // ...
     }`
2. Put APICalls Service in the providers:[] in app.module.ts

   `providers:[APICalls]`